# Promoting an app in the Ubuntu Software Center through a ratings and reviews API

Tags: software-center, python, application-development

As an app author, I would like to promote my app in Ubuntu. One nice way to do it is to encourage users to submit their reviews and ratings to the Software Center.

It would be really cool if I could just add a 'Submit review' button in the About dialog of my app to make it extremely easy to write and submit a review.

Is there a Software Center ratings and reviews API that I can access through Python to achieve that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ubuntu Software Center can be launched with a package name:

```
software-center chromium-browser
```

which displays the 'Write your own review' action, but you usually have to scroll to see it.

If you'd like to be able to display your own review form and submit via the **ratings and reviews API**, you can do so with the `submit_review` API call, but it'll require an authenticated API call... see "Making authenticated API calls" at:

http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~rnr-developers/rnr-server/rnrclient/view/head:/doc/quickstart.rst

Comment: Thanks Michael! I think the second option is what I was looking for. But just in case it proves too difficult to implement, I might be looking at just launching Software Center with the app selected so that the review can be done there as your first suggestion.