# How can users rate apps?

Tags: application-development

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Promoting an app in the Ubuntu Software Center through a ratings and reviews API](https://askubuntu.com/questions/143593/promoting-an-app-in-the-ubuntu-software-center-through-a-ratings-and-reviews-api)

Is there an URI we can open from an app so that the user is redirected to the ubuntu app store client in order for the user to be able to rate the app ?

Comment: Did you try `apt://package`?

Comment: not yet, but I'd rather know the URL before submitting. So far not submitted... I'll have to look it the doc was improved.